# How to store Multidimensional array in Database - using laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I want to save students course information into database courses table. Student can add multiple course, class time and section at a time using a form. Here is details of **courses** table:

```
**id, 
nsu_id
course,
section,
class_start,
class_end**
```

**Form (View)**

```
            <form method="POST" action="/store">
            @csrf
            {{-- clone start from here --}}  
                <div class="parent">
                    <div id="form-set">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="course" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Course & Section') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <select type="text" class="form-control" name="course[]">
                                    <option>Course</option>
                                    <option>cse 115</option>
                                    <option>cse 215</option>
                                    <option>cse 311</option>
                                    <option>cse 411</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <select type="number" class="form-control" name="section[]">
                                    <option>Section</option>
                                    <option>1</option>
                                    <option>2</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="Class Timing" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Class Timing') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <select type="text" class="form-control" name="class_start[]">
                                    <option>Start</option>
                                    <option>08:00 AM</option>
                                    <option>09:40 AM</option>
                                    <option>11:20 AM</option>
                                    <option>01:00 PM</option>
                                    <option>02:40 PM</option>
                                    <option>04:20 PM</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <select type="text" class="form-control" name="class_end[]" >
                                    <option>End</option>
                                    <option>9:30</option>
                                    <option>11:10</option>
                                    <option>12:50</option>
                                    <option>2:30</option>
                                    <option>4:10</option>
                                    <option>5:50</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row justify-content-center"  style="margin-top: -11%">
                    <div class="col-md-10" style="visibility: hidden"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" id="add">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#add').click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $("#form-set").clone().appendTo(".parent");
                        });
                    });
                </script>
           {{-- Clone end here --}}

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="nsu_id" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('NSU ID') }}</label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="number" required class="form-control" name="nsu_id"  placeholder="Exp. 1520836042">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            {{ __('Register') }}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**Model**

```
class Course extends Model
{
  protected $table='courses';
  protected $fillable=[
    'nsu_id','course','section','class_start','class_end'
  ];

}
```

**Migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('nsu_id');
        $table->string('course');
        $table->integer('section');
        $table->string('class_start');
        $table->string('class_end');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This is what I have done to controller and i am getting **Array to string conversion exception**.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
     $data[]=$request->all();
     //dd($data);
     $courseData=[];
     foreach($data as $data){
         $pointData[]=[
             'nsu_id'=>$data['nsu_id'],
             'course'=>$data['course'],
             'section'=>$data['section'],
             'class_start'=>$data['class_start'],
             'class_end'=>$data['class_end'],
         ];
     }
     DB::table('courses')->insert($courseData);

     return redirect()->to('/home');
    }
```

When i am trying get the value using helper function **dd($data);**

```
    array:1 [▼
      0 => array:6 [▼
        "_token" => "2AspZiawULQy4fMikkBTRzjvUxPVnZPPonJrZAUy"
        "course" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "cse 115"
          1 => "cse 215"
        ]
        "section" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "1"
          1 => "2"
        ]
        "class_start" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "08:00 AM"
          1 => "09:40 AM"
        ]
        "class_end" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "9:30"
          1 => "11:10"
        ]
        "nsu_id" => "1520836042"
      ]
    ]
```

**Error:** Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `courses` (`class_end`, `class_start`, `course`, `nsu_id`, `section`) values (9:30, 08:00 AM, cse 115, 1520836042, 1))

**Any kind of help will be highly appreciated**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a lot of time, i am successfully solve my own problem in a different way. Thanks @mchljams for all his kind assistance and cooperation.

```
            $nsu_id=$request->nsu_id;
            if (count($request->course)>0) {
                foreach($request->course as $item => $value)
                    $data[$value]=array(
                        'nsu_id'=>$nsu_id,
                        'course'=>$request->course[$item],
                        'section'=>$request->section[$item],
                        'class_start'=>$request->class_start[$item],
                        'class_end'=>$request->class_end[$item],
                    );
                    Course::insert($data);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking into Laravel's Eloquent ORM. From the [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent):

> "Each database table has a corresponding "Model" which is used to interact with >that table. Models allow you to query for data in your tables, as well as >**insert new records** into the table."

```
$course = new Course();
$course->nsu_id = $request->nsu_id
$course->course = $request->course
$course->section = $request->->section
$course->class_start = $request->class_start
$course->class_end = $request->class_end
$course->save();
```

or if you configure to allow [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)

```
Course::create($request);
```

Also, you should have a look at [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation) on that incoming request to ensure your users are not making mistakes, or some bad actor is not trying to compromize your application.

### EDIT 1

Per the comments, you don't want to try to pursue the Eloquent solution. $data['course'], is an array.  Since your database, as defined in your schema expects a string, that will be a problem. So here are some ideas on how to convert your array data to strings.

**Comma Separated via implode()**

```
foreach($data as $data){
         $pointData[]=[
             'nsu_id'=>$data['nsu_id'],
             'course'=>implode(',',$data['course']),
             'section'=>implode(',',$data['section']),
             'class_start'=>implode(',',$data['class_start']),
             'class_end'=>implode(',',$data['class_end']),
         ];
     }
```

**JSON String via json_encode()**

```
foreach($data as $data){
         $pointData[]=[
             'nsu_id'=>$data['nsu_id'],
             'course'=json_encode($data['course']),
             'section'=>json_encode($data['section']),
             'class_start'=>json_encode($data['class_start']),
             'class_end'=>json_encode($data['class_end']),
         ];
     }
```

### Edit 2

In the comments you asked how to do mupltiple inserts

**Inserting Multiple Rows into the Database**

Have a look at [Laravel's DB Insert Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#inserts), but here is the example from that page:

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    ['email' => 'taylor@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
    ['email' => 'dayle@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
]);
```

Comment: I tried this way before and even i already look into Laravel's Eloquent ORM for several times. But at the end, i stuck this kinda error. I think the problem is to pass a multidimensional array into database table in a logical way.

Comment: You may have deeper architectural problems here. You might want to think through why you are trying to add information for multiple courses this way. A Pivot table may provide more flexibility when trying to associate more than one course with a user. In this case I'd also still recommend using Eloquent models, and taking advantage of the relationships you can define there.

Comment: i include Model and Migration in my question. please check. By the way, i tried with this query: ** $courseData[]=$request->all(); foreach ($courseData as $data) {$content=new Course(); $content->nsu_id=$data['nsu_id']; $content->course=$data['course']; $content->section=$data['section']; $content->class_start=$data['class_start']; $content->class_end=$data['class_end']; $content->save();    
        }**

Comment: first of all , i am new in Laravel and still learning the best logical way.I try my best to use of Eloquent model and it's relationship.Can you please help me to give me a logical way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added some information via an edit to the answer about converting arrays to strings. Since your schema requires a string for those columns, that can be a work around. In the mean time I'd suggest reading up or watching more tutorials on Eloquent relationships.

Comment: Yeah, of course i will. But now i am looking for a basic solution for this problem. Anyway, can i get concern for this **Error:** SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'section' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `courses` (`class_end`, `class_start`, `course`, `nsu_id`, `section`) values (9:30,11:10, 08:00 AM,09:40 AM, cse 115,cse 215, 1520836042, 1,2))

Comment: Thank you much for your feedback. I appreciate your cooperation. I have last question on JSON String conversion idea[json_encode()]. Is it possible to insert input values in **different rows**. By using JSON string idea i got below result in **database** table. 
**{id,   nsu_id,       course,                        section,  class_start,                     class_end} 
{16- 1520836042- ["cse 115","cse 215"]- ["1","2"]- ["08:00 AM","09:40 AM"]- ["9:30 AM","11:10 AM"]}**

Comment: Have a look at Laravel's documentation on inserts, you will have to loop through your data to have a properly formatted array. I will update the answer one more time with more info.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the foreach in controller is pretty strange. why? :

`foreach $data as $data`

AND, leave `$courseData` empty and give it to insert.

Fixed version:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data[]=$request->all();
    $courseData=[];
    foreach($data as $d){
       $courseData[]= [
          'nsu_id'=> $d['nsu_id'],
          'course'=> $d['course'],
          'section'=> $d['section'],
          'class_start'=> $d['class_start'],
          'class_end'=> $d['class_end'],
        ]
    }
    DB::table('courses')->insert($courseData);

    return redirect()->to('/home');
}
```

The error you have is about giving the `insert` method an empty array as input instead of a string.

After fixing this problem you will realize that your code still doesn't work because your post values are also an array, you must think again about the input names of your form and reconstructing your data for easier and more usable logical form.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.First of all, I am new in Laravel and still learning. I took help from google to solve this specific problem .Yeah, still my code is not working. for your concern, I did several way to solve this problem include not to take array for input names in the form, ignore foreach loop in the controller. But at the end, i stuck this kinda error. Can you please help me to give me a logical way. Thanks in advance.